# Change the size of heading on pdf export

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, pdflatex, heading

I am looking to change the size and properties of specific level headings in org mode when exporting to pdf. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to change the size of a heading is to redefine the size command that is used. E.g. the article class defines a section heading with a `\Large` size. You can then add this at the beginning of your org file:

```
#LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\Large}{\LARGE}
```

to make it a little bigger. Unfortunately, that will change everything that is specified as `\Large`, not just headings, but if your file does not use that, you should be OK. The standard sizes that LaTeX defines can be found on p.220 of Lamport's book; they can also be found at https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/ and probably many other places.

Note that this trick uses LaTeX features: that is going to be necessary, no matter what solution you adopt. Org-mode itself does not know anything about the size of headings when exporting to PDF, so you will need to use some LaTeX in order to change the size (or any other property of the heading).

Comment: Thank you. is it not possible for org-mode to give a particular size to particular levels of headings ??

Comment: I don't think so. Org mode produces a LaTeX file that has (mostly) no size information in it (exceptions: there is limited support for sizing tables and images). It is LaTeX that decides how to print the headings.

Comment: Thank you i will try using macros then :)